# setQueryParams; Parameter value did not match expected type

Tags: java, sql, jakarta-ee, primefaces

[image]

[image]

Ok, so I have the user inputing a date, which is to be queried in java using **em.createQuery**.  As you can see from the screenshots, I have the input data going in as **pattern="dd-MMM-yy** (thats how its stored in the server), but I have also tried this without the pattern tag and it still does not work.  The actual error is at the **setQueryParams(q)** though and I haven't been able to figure out what it is.  Anyone have an idea to where I might look?  THanks.

Answer (score 1):

You haven't shown us what `q` is, but it sounds like you are giving a `java.lang.String` where a `java.util.Date` is expected.

Also, what is up with writing strings like

```
queryStr += " and c." + "dateCreated" + " >=:" + ...
```

? that looks like a pain to maintain/read.

Comment: Yeah, I actually only had the else statement to start off and added the other 2 for the date, but just kept it in the same format. I will try using SimpleDateFormat like @eric said.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with Matt b, looks like you're supplying a string and expecting a date (though it's hard to read the text on your screenshot). Take a look at [SimpleDateFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html), and use the "parse" method to derive a Date object from a String.

Edit:

It looks like you're date is in a string format that looks something like this:

Tue Jan 01 00:00:00 EST 2013

Here is code that should parse a string in that format:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    String dateString = "Tue Jan 01 00:00:00 EST 2013";
    SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd hh:mm:ss z yyyy");
    try {
        Date date = format.parse(dateString);
        System.out.println(date.toString());
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

I can't tell by looking at your log statements if the square brackets are part of your string or not, if they are you'd have to include those in your format:

```
SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("[EEE MMM dd hh:mm:ss z yyyy]");
```

Note I don't have your *exact* date string here, so I may have made a mistake transcribing it from your image. Use a breakpoint or a print statement to get the exact format of the String q.

Of course, this is all under the assumption that q is a string, based on your logs it seems like that's the case.

Comment: Sorry, the website must have shrunk my image. I tried setting this up, but am now getting an "unparsable date" message.  The input I have going into the parser is the same as what I have in quotes there.                                  `DateFormat formatter1;
     formatter1 = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yy");
     try {
      Date fdc = (Date)formatter1.parse(key);
      queryStr += " and c.dateCreated" + " >= :" + fdc + " ";`

Comment: If I open the image in another tab, I can see it better.

Comment: Also, are you sure about where the error is coming from? It looks like q should be of Type Query, but the error is complaining about getting a string where a Date is expected? Seems off...

Comment: Wow, your right.  Sorry, working on old code that someone else did.  The problem was in the setQueryParams method its converting everything to string, which I didn't even think to look in there because I was using step over and not step into.  Damn..